# Can't multiple play on iOS/Android chrome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, html5-audio

I can play multiple on desktop chrome
but I can't on chrome of iOS/Android version.
Does anyone who solve the issue?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>multiple track test</title>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
<button id="button">play</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
            var player = null;
            var count = 0;
            function play() {
                var currentPlayer = player;
                currentPlayer.addEventListener('ended',function(){
                        currentPlayer.pause();
                        play();
                },false);
                currentPlayer.play();
                player = new Audio(count + ".mp3");
                player.load();
                count += 1;
            }
            function init() {
                player = new Audio("0.mp3");
                var button = document.getElementById("button");
                button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                        play();
                },false);
            }
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are different browsers and support different features. For instance you can record audio in the desktop version but not on the phone.

Comment: umm but I can hear 0.mp3 and 1.mp3 multiply. but not 2.mp3 ...

Comment: Can you post a link to this test page?  I wonder if it's beefed up garbage collection on the mobile browser. Maybe you should create an array of currentPlayers and hold all the Audio objects that are playing in the array.